# How to capture the two queryparams in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have written a class method like this :--

```
  @GET
@Path("updatestatus")
public Response updateStatus(@DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("vi") String vi,        @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("chatstatus") String chatStatus){

    String status = vi + "  "+ chatStatus;
    System.out.println(status);


    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Should I better use @Context in these cases where more than one queryparam is being read?

Comment: That should work (if `chatStatus` is a single GET parameter).

Comment: What is meant by single GET parameter? The value of chatStatus is a String

Comment: single Get parameter means that you do not send an array of parameters. PS: you probably have a better possibility than the one described by Sanjay.

Comment: You were correct Sir, the URI I was using to hit the resource was not correct.Thanks for the clarification. Please elaborate that possibility or instead write one, I would accept that earnestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better way to do that for your problem, and your example should work (if you send the correct parameters to the correct rest resource).

Answer (score 1):

Better to do this way.

```
  @GET
   public Response updateStatus(@Context UriInfo info) {

        String vi = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("vi");
        return Response
           .status(200)
           .entity("update status is called, vi: " + vi).build();
```

refer more here.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrst/

Comment: Please put the information regarding the Queryparams back as part of the answer.

Comment: There are two params add chatStatus also in the body of the method.